# Client requires an Account SID

Tags: node-red

Is there a way to edit the config.json file of the Twilio node module so that it explicitly sets the Account SID and Auth Token for the sms-twilio node. Can I achieve this by editing the flow.json file?

As instructed by the twilio modules README.MD file, I have tried to edit the config.json of the twilio node to incorporate my Account SID and Auth Token, but when I run node-red I still get the same "Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token set explicitly".

```
moxa@Moxa:~/.node-red$
moxa@Moxa:~/.node-red$ node-red
31 Jan 17:00:54 - [info]

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

31 Jan 17:00:54 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.19.5
31 Jan 17:00:54 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.14.0
31 Jan 17:00:54 - [info] Linux 4.1.0-ltsi-rt-uc8100-me+ arm LE
31 Jan 17:01:00 - [info] Loading palette nodes
31 Jan 17:01:07 - [warn] rpi-gpio : Raspberry Pi specific node set inactive
31 Jan 17:01:07 - [warn] rpi-gpio : Cannot find Pi RPi.GPIO python library
31 Jan 17:01:34 - [info] Settings file  : /home/moxa/.node-red/settings.js
31 Jan 17:01:34 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
31 Jan 17:01:34 - [info] User directory : /home/moxa/.node-red
31 Jan 17:01:34 - [warn] Projects disabled : editorTheme.projects.enabled=false
31 Jan 17:01:34 - [info] Flows file     : /home/moxa/.node-red/flows_Moxa.json
31 Jan 17:01:35 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
31 Jan 17:01:35 - [warn]

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.

If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
your credentials.

You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
---------------------------------------------------------------------

31 Jan 17:01:35 - [info] Starting flows
31 Jan 17:01:35 - [error] [amazon config:fb6e3837.b0fad8] TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessKey' of undefined
31 Jan 17:01:35 - [error] [sms:4dcdccae.502fa4] Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token set explicitly or via the TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN environment variables
31 Jan 17:01:35 - [error] [sms:cf027e1e.e853e] Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token set explicitly or via the TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN environment variables
31 Jan 17:01:35 - [info] Started flows
31 Jan 17:01:45 - [info] [debug:Debugger]

Per Tank Level: 60%
Raw Tank Level: 19916
31 Jan 17:01:45 - [info] [debug:Debugger]
```

This is the config.json file that is supposed to supply the required SID and Auth Token.

```
//Configuration for running tests and examples against the Twilio API
module.exports = {
    accountSid:'**************************', // Actual Json isnt "*"'s
    authToken:'***************************',
    from:'*********', //The Twilio number you've bought or configured
    to:'************' //The number you would like to send messages to for testing
};
```

Comment: Edit the question to explicitly say which node-red node you are using, I'm assuming it is `node-red-contrib-sms-twilio` if so you should be setting those values via the config node not a file

Comment: Yes the node is node-red-contrib-sms-twilio, I am not able to access the web configuration page because I am using node-red on a embedded computer without a graphics card. This limits me to only editing the JSON files. To get around this I tried to create an instanced browser using node-red-contrib-nbrowser to configure node-red via a browser, but because there's no graphics card, the window never popped up.

Comment: No it doesn't, you can connect to the Node-RED editor from any computer that has a browser. Just point your browser at http://<ip address of device>:1880

Comment: You couldn't be more right, thank you so much. Typically I thought when I type in the IP of the device it takes me to the devices configuration page, but adding the port 1880 takes you to the node-red config page even though it says its broadcasting at 127.0.0.1?